# Facebook Application: Secure Canvas URL

Tags: php, facebook, security

I got a domain so that I can start a facebook app. but while I was filling up the basics, (canvas page, ur..etc) I've encounter the secure canvas url, and this really messed up my mind, I've been googling for several hours now, and I'm kinda desperate. lol. I've sign up on StartSSL since it's I'm just doing this for learning purpose and its free.

I get this error whenever I got to secure http

**SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.**

Here's what I did:

-I put all the content of 'src' in facebook-php-sdk on my folder 'ssl' which is also a subdomain of my website. I put my appID and appSecret inside the index.php

-On my SSL/TLS Manager (I'm using cpanel) I filled all the requirements on the textfield to have a CSR

-I copied the csr and submit it on StartSSL

-After that the LLS site prompt me that I should put a subdomain.

-Then they gave me a CRT. after that I went to my cpanel again, paste it on crt manager and install

I really thought that after doing this my url can be browse on https. Please help me, Did I missed something here?

Comment: Do you use the latest facebook php sdk?

Comment: Have you visited your website on https:// first - does this work? Check if there is a certificate error.

Comment: @robbie it's the same error that I get

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my previous facebook application project.That was because,the server in which the application was hosted didn't have the SSL certificate.We solved the issue by getting SSL certificate for the server.